# Match a url that does not contain certain word

Tags: regex

I need some help for a regular expressions for not matching urls like these one:

/Common/Download.php?file=/path/to/file.pdf

and instead to matching these static urls:

/path/to/file.pdf

I have read many post (also in this site) but nothing seems to works as expected.

Thanks for your helps.

Lorenzo.

**UPDATE**

Sorry if this post is not so complete. I post more information to obtain a better help.

The regular expression that I need must work with Apache module mod_rewrite (and also with the module mod_rewrite of IIS (maybe this is not the right name) that is compatible with the module of Apache (as from my knowledge), if possible ) and must redirect the matching static urls (only of the second type, as from my post) to a specific page.

Thanks again.

Lorenzo.

Comment: So what is the pattern you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your programming language and regex parser, I'm keeping my regex really generic, but something like this should get you close:

```
^/([A-Za-z0-9]+/)+[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]{3,4}$
```

This matches a string starting with a slash, one or more directories separated by slashes, and ending with a filename with a three or four character file extension.

This means /path/to/some/really/buried/file.html would match too.

Using an interactive regular expression evaluator is a great way to rapidly write and debug regular expressions, especially if you are new to them.  I really like [The Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to repeat the forward slash lowercase characters  pattern in a non capturing group and repeat that. Then match the file extension `.pdf`

[`^(?:/[a-z]+){3}\.pdf$`](https://regex101.com/r/ACAHOT/1)

**Explanation**

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Non capturing group `(?:`
- Match one or more lowercase characters `[a-z]+`
- Close the non capturing group and match 3 times `){3}`
- Match a dot `\.` and `pdf`
- The end of the string `$`

Or repeat the group 2 times and for the filename use `\w+`

[`^(?:/[a-z]+){2}/\w+\.pdf$`](https://regex101.com/r/avWR2s/1)

If you want to match your example static url and maybe longer or shorter paths like `/path/file.pdf` or `/dir/path/to/file.pdf` you could for example use:

[`^(?:/\w+)+\.\w+$`](https://regex101.com/r/YcVzLk/1)